# How to grep content of file and create another file with grepped content?

Tags: unix, awk

I want to get grep content of file matching particular text and then want to save all those records which matches particular text to new file and also want to make sure that matched content is removed from original file.

```
    296949657|QL|163744584|163744581|20441||
    292465754|RE|W757|3012|301316469|00|
    296950717|RC|7264|00001|013|27082856203|
    292465754|QL|191427266|191427266|16405||
    296950717|RC|7264|AETNAACTIVE|HHRPPO|27082856203|
    299850356|RC|7700|153447|0891185100102-A|W19007007201|
    292465754|RE|W757|3029|301316469|00|
    299850356|RC|7700|153447|0891185100104-A|W19007007201|
    293695591|QL|743559415|743559410|18452||
    297348183|RC|6602|E924|0048|CD101699303|
    297348183|RC|6602|E924|0051|CD101699303|
    108327882|QL|613440276|613440275|17435||
```

I have written awk and it works as expected for small files but for larger files is not working as expected....am sure that i have missed something...

```
awk '{print $0 > ($0~/RC/?"RC_RECORDS":"TEST.DAT")}' TEST.DAT
```

any thoughts on how to fix this.

**Update 1**

Now in above file, i always want to check values of column two to |RC| and if it matches then move that record to RC_RECORDS file and if values matches to |RE| then move it to RE_RECORDS, how can this be done.

Case 1:

So for example if i have records as

```
108327882|RE|613440276|613440275|RC||
```

then it should go to RE_RECORDS file.

Case 2:

```
108327882|RC|613440276|613440275|RE||
```

then it should go to RE_RECORDS

Case 3:

```
108327882|QL|613440276|613440275|RC||
```

then it should not go to either RE_RECORDS or RC_RECORDS

Case 4:

```
108327882|QL|613440276|613440275|RE||
```

then it should not go to either RE_RECORDS or RC_RECORDS

My hunch is that

```
awk '/\|RC\|/ {print > "RC_RECORDS.DAT";next} {print > "NEWTEST.DAT"}' TEST.DAT | awk '$2 == "RC"'
awk '/\|RE\|/ {print > "RE_RECORDS.DAT";next} {print > "FINAL_NEWTEST.DAT"}' NEWTEST.DAT | awk '$2 == "RE"'
```

but wanted to check if there's an better and quicker solution out there that can be used.

**Update 2**

[image]

**Update 3**
[image]

Comment: What about that isn't working for large files?

Comment: I have total of 88M records in file and for RC and RE i have 29M and 22M records respectively but when i run above awk command then for RC counts come out to be 54 and RE count comes out to be 36 which is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

**Option 1**

```
awk -F'|' '
   $2=="RC" {print >"RC_RECORDS.TXT";next}
   $2=="RE" {print >"RE_RECORDS.TXT";next}
   {print >"OTHER_RECORDS.TXT"}' file
```

You can put it all on one line if you prefer, like this:

```
awk -F'|' '$2=="RC"{print >"RC_RECORDS.TXT";next} $2=="RE"{print >"RE_RECORDS.TXT";next}{print >"OTHER_RECORDS.TXT"}' file
```

**Option 2**

Or you can see how `grep` compares for speed/readability:

```
grep -E  "^[[:alnum:]]+\|RC\|"  file > RC_RECORDS.TXT &
grep -E  "^[[:alnum:]]+\|RE\|"  file > RE_RECORDS.TXT &
grep -vE "^[[:alnum:]]+\|R[CE]" file > OTHER_RECORDS.TXT &
wait
```

**Option 3**

This solution uses 2 `awk` processes and maybe achieves better parallelism in the I/O. The first `awk` extracts the `RC` records to a file and passes the rest onwards. The second `awk` extracts the `RE` records to a file and passes the rest on to be written to the `OTHER_RECORDS.TXT` file.

```
awk -F'|' '$2=="RC"{print >"RC_RECORDS.TXT";next} 1' file | awk -F'|' '$2=="RE"{print >"RE_RECORDS.TXT";next} 1' > OTHER_RECORDS.TXT
```

I created an 88M record file (3 GB), and ran some test on a desktop iMac as follows:

```
Option 1: 65 seconds
Option 2: 92 seconds
Option 3: 53 seconds
```

Your mileage may vary.

My file looks like this, i.e. 33% RE records, 33% RC records and rest junk:

```
00000000|RE|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000001|RC|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000002|XX|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000003|RE|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000004|RC|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000005|XX|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000006|RE|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000007|RC|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000008|XX|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
00000009|RE|abcdef|ghijkl|mnopq|rstu
```

Sanity Check

```
wc -l *TXT
29333333 OTHER_RECORDS.TXT
29333333 RC_RECORDS.TXT
29333334 RE_RECORDS.TXT
88000000 total
```

Comment: I don't know - it depends on lots of factors - OS caching policy, awk implementation, grep implementation, disk performance... try it with the `time` command in front of each.

Comment: both approach is taking pretty much same time and so i will go with my former approach.

Comment: In above situation, I want to always compare 2nd field of file to |RC| or |RE|, how should i accomplish that, please see my updated question above.

Comment: Suggested answer would not work for case 3 and case 4 in my updated question section.

Comment: Use 4th awk example in my answer

Comment: Ok, running it through different scenarios and will update in some time

Comment: Oooops! `I` have missed a double quote!

Comment: Please have a look at the "Performance Idea" in my answer too.

Comment: Working on that...but for column 1, i cannot make an assumption that it would always be digits, it can be alpha numeric values or also just alphabets, so grep is looking very risky to me

Comment: Only thing am sure is that 2nd Column would be |RC| or |RE| or |QL| or |HB| or |CA| or |RX| or |MC|

Comment: Also using awk script above we are creating two files RE_RECORDS and RC_RECORDS but are we removing RC and RE records from Main file or just copying them to RC/RE files respectively? My requirement is that I have one Main file then out of that main files i need to create 3 files...RC File capturing RC records where column 2 matches RC, RE File capturing RE records where column 2 matches RE and Final File which has all remaining records from Main File, also we need to preserve Main file in it's orignial form.

Comment: @Rachel Updated once more.

Comment: Following your previous suggestions, i have updated my script as shown in update 3 and i think it will work, only thing am more concerned right now is to improve performance of this script.

Comment: @Rachel No! You didn't do as I said - you are making 2 passes over the file with that code, which will take longer, and your `NEW_ECCR_PROD.DAT` will also have `RE` records in it and your `FINAL_ECCR_PROD.DAT` will have `RC` records in it. Did you try the `grep` suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57823/discussion-between-rachel-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: tried `awk -F'|' '$2=="RC"{print >"RC_RECORDS.TXT";next} $2=="RE"{print >"RE_RECORDS.TXT";next}{print >"OTHER_RECORDS.TXT"}' file` but in this case, everything goes to OTHER_RECORDS file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Mark, i think i will go with 2 approach as am not sure about underlying hardware on prod boxes, my process is still running as it has to process around 800 million records, let's see how long it would take.

Comment: @Rachel It may help your performance if you can write the output files to different disk drives, e.g. RC_RECORDS to /var, RE_RECORDS to /home and OTHER_RECORDS to /somewhere/else. Use `mount` or `df` to see different drives.